# How to get the time difference in human format (time ago ... etc) but in multilingual style

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there any view helper or a library in zend with which i get for example the difference between two time stamps but automatically to put 'y li a' in front of the time .This is for example the french standard for time ago...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, but maybe this will help:

```
<?php

/**
 * Return a human readable diff between two times (e.g. 3 years 4 months 8 days 3 hours)
 * This is locale aware and supports automatic translation
 *
 * @category   View Helpers
 * @author     Drew Phillips <drew [at] drew [.] co.il>
 * @copyright  None
 * @license    BSD License http://opensource.org/licenses/bsd-3-clause
 * @version    1.0
 * @link       http://drew.co.il
 */
class My_View_Helper_TimeDiff extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    protected static $_locale       = null;
    protected static $_translations = null;

    /**
     * Return the diff between two times in human readable format
     * @param int    $timestamp    The timestamp of the time to diff
     * @param string $format       The format string used to control which date units are output (TODO: improve by incrementing lower values (i.e. add 12 to months if there is 1 year but years are not displayed))
     * @param int    $now          The timestamp used as the current time, if null, the current time is used
     * @return string              The human readable date diff in the language of the locale
     */
    public function timeDiff($timestamp, $format = null, $now = null)
    {
        if (null === $format) $format = '%y %m %d %h %i';
        if (null === $now)    $now    = time();

        if (!$this->isValidTimestamp($timestamp)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('$timestamp parameter to timeDiff is not a valid timestamp');
        } else if (!$this->isValidTimestamp($now)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('$now parameter to timeDiff is not a valid timestamp');
        } else if ($timestamp > $now) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('The value given for $timestamp cannot be greater than $now');
        }

        if (self::$_locale == null) {
            $locale = null;
            $list   = array();

            try {
                $locale = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale');
            } catch (Zend_Exception $ex) {
                $default = Zend_Locale::getDefault(); // en if nothing set

                try {
                    $locale = new Zend_Locale();
                } catch (Zend_Locale_Exception $ex) {
                    $locale = new Zend_Locale($default);
                }
            }

            self::$_locale = $locale;
            self::$_translations = Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('unit', $locale);
        }

        $table    = self::$_translations;
        $past     = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp));
        $current  = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now));
        $interval = $current->diff($past);

        $parts = $interval->format('%y %m %d %h %i %s %a');

        $weeks = 0;
        list($years, $months, $days, $hours, $minutes, $seconds, $total_days) = explode(' ', $parts);

        /* uncomment to handle weeks
        if ($days >= 7) {
            $weeks = (int)($days / 7);
            $days  %= 7;
        }
        */

        $diff = array();

        if (strpos($format, '%y') !== false && $years > 0) {
            $diff[] = str_replace('{0}', $years, $table['year'][($years != 1 || !isset($table['year']['one']) ? 'other' : 'one')]);
        }

        if (strpos($format, '%m') !== false && $months > 0) {
            $diff[] = str_replace('{0}', $months, $table['month'][($months != 1 || !isset($table['month']['one']) ? 'other' : 'one')]);
        }

        if (strpos($format, '%d') !== false && $days > 0) {
            $diff[] = str_replace('{0}', $days, $table['day'][($days != 1 || !isset($table['day']['one']) ? 'other' : 'one')]);
        }

        if (strpos($format, '%h') !== false && $hours > 0) {
            $diff[] = str_replace('{0}', $hours, $table['hour'][($hours != 1 || !isset($table['hour']['one']) ? 'other' : 'one')]);
        }

        if (strpos($format, '%i') !== false && $minutes > 0) {
            $diff[] = str_replace('{0}', $minutes, $table['minute'][($minutes != 1 || !isset($table['minute']['one']) ? 'other' : 'one')]);
        }

        return implode(' ', $diff);
    }

    protected function isValidTimestamp($timestamp)
    {
        $ts = (int)$timestamp;
        $d  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);

        return strtotime($d) === $ts;
    }
}
```

Once registered, call it like this from your view:

```
<?php echo $this->timeDiff($object->pastTimestamp) ?> $this->_xlate('ago');
```

Example output:

```
1 année 5 mois 15 jours 21 heures 56 minutes il ya
1 год 5 месяца 15 дня 22 часа 1 минута назад
```

Note that the helper doesn't handle the "ago" part which in some languages (French) goes in front of the difference, and in others (English) it goes at the end.  You also need to have this translation string defined in your own translation files, ZF doesn't have a translation for it.  Ideally that logic would be built into the helper but I have not done so.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp is a number, you can simply substract the start time from the end time to get the difference.  You could do something like this:

```
public function timeDiff($timestampFrom, $timestampTo) {

$timeDiff = new Zend_Date($timestampTo - $timestampFrom, Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);

$output = "il y a ";

//Check the number of days:
if($timeDiff->getTimestamp > 60*60*24) $output .= $timeDiff->get(Zend_Date::DAY).' jours, ';
//Check the hours
if($timeDiff->getTimestamp > 60*60) $output .= $timeDiff->get(Zend_Date::HOUR).' heures, ';
//Check the minutes
if($timeDiff->getTimestamp > 60) $output .= $timeDiff->get(Zend_Date::MINUTE).' minutes et ';
//Check the seconds
$output .= $timeDiff->get(Zend_Date::SECOND)." secondes";

return $output;
}
```

And Matthieu is right in his comment, there is no such thing as 'y li a' in French.  You probably meant 'il y a'.  ;)

Comment: thanks for the answer, and yes you are right i totally misspelled time ago in french